# Haircuts on Fast Days

Tags: halacha, fast-days, hair

Is one allowed to take a haircut on a fast day like Tzom Gedaliah and or  Asarah B'Teves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  It's a fast day, but no customs of mourning.

Comment: source?................

Comment: According to the Aruch HaShulchan (OH 550:3), there are indeed customs of mourning on regular fast days -- specifically not bathing in warm water.

Answer (score 1):

Al Pi Kabbalah(Sha'ar HaKavvanot Drush Eruv Shabbat) one should only have a haircut on Erev Shabbat/Yom Tov.

Comment: Sorry, I can't yet comment on answers, but for the first answer: you will get a chance to apply the question this year, even according to your view, since it's one of those rare years in which [Asarah B'Teves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenth_of_Tevet) falls out on a Friday.

Comment: the Mishnah berurah says it is better not to also

Comment: Odd, because Al Pi Kabbala (Magen Avraham beshem Kavvanot HaAri OC 251 sk 5) you can't get a haircut Friday afternoons. That's not a lot of time remaining!

Comment: Right.  One must cut one's hair in the morning after davening and before mikvah.  Likewise one should have their hair cut only be a Jew.